# Nest React components in ClojureScript with Hiccup

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript

I'm trying to use [react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax) like here:
http://blob.tomerweller.com/reagent-import-react-components-from-npm

How can I nest the `Node` component in the `Context` one with Hiccup formatted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defn ui                                                                        
 []                                                                            
 (let [react-mathjax (aget js/window "deps" "react-mathjax")                   
       ctx (aget react-mathjax "Context")                                      
       node (aget react-mathjax "Node")]                                       
  [:div                                                                        
    [:h1 "Hello world"]
    [:> ctx [:> node "2+2"]]]))
```